# unit test static constructor w/ different config values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static-constructor

I have a class with a static constructor which I use to read the app.config values. How do I unit test the class with different configuration values. I'm thinking of running each test in different app domain so I can have static constructor executed for each test - but I have two problems here: 
1. I do not know how to run each test run in separate app domain and 
2. how do I change configuration settings at run time?

Can someone please help me with this? Or anyone has a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Extract that logic into a non-static class abd call it from within the cctor. Now you can test that new class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test .Net being able to load data from config files.
Instead, try to concentrate on testing your own logic.

Change your class so that it gets the configuration values from its constructor (or via properties), and then test it as you would with any other dependency.

Along the way you have also moved your class towards [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

As per the configuration loading - concentrate this logic in a separate, non-static class.

---

EDIT:
Separate the configuration logic into another class. something like this:

```
public static class ConfigurationLoader
{
    static ConfigurationLoader()
    {
        // Dependency1 = LoadFromConfiguration();
        // Dependency2 = LoadFromConfiguration();
    }

    public static int Dependency1 { get; private set; }
    public static string Dependency2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, when you instantiate your class, inject it with the dependencies:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly int m_Dependency1;
    private readonly string m_Dependency2;

    public MyClass(int dependency1, string dependency2)
    {
        m_Dependency1 = dependency1;
        m_Dependency2 = dependency2;
    }

    public char MethodUnderTest()
    {
        if (m_Dependency1 > 42)
        {
            return m_Dependency2[0];
        }

        return ' ';
    }
}

public class MyClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MethodUnderTest_dependency1is43AndDependency2isTest_ReturnsT()
    {
        var underTest = new MyClass(43, "Test");
        var result = underTest.MethodUnderTest();
        Assert.Equal('T', result);
    }
}

...

var myClass = new MyClass(ConfigurationLoader.Dependency1, ConfigurationLoader.Dependency2);
```

You could go on and use IOC containers, but your problem of testing MyClass with different inputs is solved by this simple testable design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we have used static constructor to avoid reading the values from the config values on every calls. The unit tests I'm writing are not to test .NET being able to load data from config files but to test the behavior of the methods with different values.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just stick your static constructor into a static method then execute that method in the static block.

Answer (score 0):

If you read from `(Web)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, that is just a NameValueCollection, so you can replace your code that reads `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` directly with code, that reads from any NameValueCollection.

Just move out your actual configuration parsing to a static method from the static ctor. Static ctor calls that static method and passes `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, but you can call that parser method from the test code, and verify the config parsing without actually touching a file, or messing with appdomains.

But on the long run, really inject your configuration parameters as seldary suggested. Create a configuration class, read the actual values at application start, and set up your IoC container to supply the same configuration instance to all requesters.

This makes further testing easier too, because you classes don't read from a global static configuration instance. You can just pass in a specific configuration instance for differet tests. Of course create a factory method for your tests, to construct a global configuration, so you don't have to do it manually all the time...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem recently. The only difference was that the configuration value was coming from database instead of app.config. I was able to resolve it using TypeInitializer.

```
[Test]
public void TestConfigurationInStaticConstructor()
{
    // setup configuraton to test
    // ...

    // init static constructor
    ReaderTypeInit();

    // Assert configuration effect
    // ...

    // reset static ctor to prevent other existing tests (that may depend on original static ctor) fail
    ReaderTypeInit();
}

// helper method
private void ReaderTypeInit()
{
    typeof(< your class with static ctor>).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
}
```